# Use Lambda@Edge to force a CloudFront origin request

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I have a scenario where I am using CloudFront to cache a user specific API response.  The data in the API response will not change very often and is used across multiple places in my app.  However, when the data DOES change, I would like the user to be able to hit a "refresh" button that forces CloudFront to go get new content and then cache this new content.

I have looked at CloudFront and the Cache-Control: no-cache and Cache-Control: max-age=0 headers, but as far as I can tell these are ignored by CloudFront.

I have also looked at invalidating cache based on a specific key, but this functionality does not seem to be supported (path based invalidation only which would affect all users instead of a specific one)

Changing one of the caching keys (a query string parameter for instance) to force a new request is also a possibility, but would require me to keep track of/manage caching keys on the client side in order to be able to access the cached response every time.

So I am down to trying to figure out how to do this with Lambda@Edge, but am struggling to find any examples of if this is possible.

CloudFront has worked great so far for my needs.  I just need to be able to force it to refresh.

Is there anyway to accomplish this using Lambda?  Or some other way I have not found (aside from writing my own caching mechanism using a database/redis/memcached/etc)?

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to cache a call to an API and the user identity is part of the cache key (ex. https://myapi/rsc?user=id).

You also want to control when the client is using the cached version or call the API to fetch a new result.

IMHO the best approach is to use versioning and add a new query parameter representing the version of your result (ex. https://myapi/rsc?user=id&version=v).

You can create a new API to update or retrieve the current version (ex. https://myapi/version). When the user hits refresh you call the API and increment the version. Then you use this new version for your API calls.